# expo for ios - 'Unable to determine runtime bundle when booting device

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

Trying to start an expo project on a Macbook (Mid-2012) and the following error occured:

*** Assertion failure in -SimDevice _onBootstrapQueue_bootWithOptions:error:, SimDevice.m:2057
2021-12-25 21:21:29.751 simctl[3424:48740] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Unable to determine runtime bundle when booting device.'

How do I fix this? Thanks in advance.

```
> expo start --ios

Starting project at /Users/johngfisher/App
Developer tools running on http://localhost:19002
Starting Metro Bundler
xcrun exited with signal: SIGABRT
2021-12-25 21:21:29.748 simctl[3424:48740] *** Assertion failure in -[SimDevice _onBootstrapQueue_bootWithOptions:error:](), SimDevice.m:2057
2021-12-25 21:21:29.751 simctl[3424:48740] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Unable to determine runtime bundle when booting device.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2f046727 __exceptionPreprocess + 250
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff6807da9e objc_exception_throw + 48
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2f06fa40 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 88
        3   Foundation                          0x00007fff317c23c6 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:file:lineNumber:description:] + 166
        4   CoreSimulator                       0x00000001063db543 -[SimDevice _onBootstrapQueue_bootWithOptions:error:] + 1915
        5   CoreSimulator                       0x00000001063dadab __35-[SimDevice bootWithOptions:error:]_block_invoke + 64
        6   CoreSimulator                       0x00000001063f2c10 __32-[SimDevice bootstrapQueueSync:]_block_invoke + 16
        7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff691c4658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
        8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff691d06ec _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 60
        9   CoreSimulator                       0x00000001063f2ba3 -[SimDevice bootstrapQueueSync:] + 169
        10  CoreSimulator                       0x00000001063dac65 -[SimDevice bootWithOptions:error:] + 178
        11  simctl                              0x000000010629f62a simctl + 169514
        12  simctl                              0x00000001062ab365 simctl + 217957
        13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff691c36c4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
        14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff691c4658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
        15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff691d2aa8 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 663
        16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff691d3097 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 92
        17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff694229f7 _pthread_wqthread + 220
        18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff69421b77 start_wqthread + 15
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
Error: xcrun exited with signal: SIGABRT
    at ChildProcess.completionListener (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/src/spawnAsync.ts:64:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:418:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
    ...
    at spawnAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/src/spawnAsync.ts:26:19)
    at xcrunAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl/src/SimControl.ts:427:18)
    at runBootAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl/src/SimControl.ts:217:11)
    at bootAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl/src/SimControl.ts:189:9)
    at action (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl/src/SimControl.ts:142:19)
    at waitForActionAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl/src/apple/utils/waitForActionAsync.ts:17:22)
    at waitForDeviceToBootAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl/src/SimControl.ts:141:10)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl/src/utils/profileMethod.ts:22:21
    at ensureSimulatorOpenAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl/src/Simulator.ts:233:30)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Answer (score 98):

I have managed to solve this one:

1. Start the Simulator separately with the following command: `open -a Simulator`
2. After this if you run `expo start` again and type `i` the Simulator will boot up properly.

Comment: this worked after 2h of headake thanks !!!!

Answer (score 7):

Had the exact same issue. My problem was, that besides iOS Simulator, I needed to manually install iOS (third item on the Xcode settings Platform tab below).

[image: Xcode settings]

Answer (score 0):

In my case the older XCode had caused the issue. Removing it also wiped out its simulators hence solved the issue. For those who do not need to have both version, it might help.